# Problem with multiple Physics2D.OverLapBox in one script picking mixed layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm trying to make a thwomp style enemy in my 2D game, I have 2 OverLapBox for it so I can check difference collision with difference checking size [(Picture for example, everything is still a placeholder)](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/387651585234305024/678644604412624907/unknown.png).

Now as you can see, there's a green outline and a red outline right on the object. The red outline will result as true when it overlap with an object in "Ground" layer, and the green should do the same but on "Player" layer instead [(as set here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/387651585234305024/678647853735870474/unknown.png) and in the code below)

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {  

        onGround = Physics2D.OverlapBox((Vector2)transform.position, collisionSize, groundLayer);

        Detected = Physics2D.OverlapBox((Vector2)transform.position, detectionSize, playerLayer);

        if (Detected && !onGround) {
            //StartCoroutine(Slamdown());
        }

    }
```

Okay, so here's the problem, right now, the Detected goes True even though there's nothing in "Player" layer in it, because it somehow also trigger with the "Ground" layer too. The green area also ingore the presence of a "Player" layer object, and also whenever I use the player character to jump into the red area where it should only trigger when something "Ground" layer enters it, it still also trigger. I've try commenting one of the OverLapBox and that didn't work, I legit have no idea where to go with this.

Comment: Can you show us how you set the two different layer masks? Also, can you confirm that the player, and the ground object, both have their correct tags set?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Not sure what you meant by set the layer mask but hope [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/387651585234305024/678908097376550932/unknown.png) and [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/387651585234305024/678908611262545920/unknown.png) help. also I can confirm that both the ground and Player has the right Layer/Tags shown [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/387651585234305024/678909026595242004/unknown.png)